# ES5 Module pattern usage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, revealing-module-pattern

Could you explain to me what is the difference between that two approaches (FirstModule and SecondModule:

```
var MyModule = (function () {
    return {
        method: function () {
            console.log("MyModule:method");
        }
    }
})();

var FirstModule = (function () {
    return {
        test: function () {
            MyModule.method();
        }
    }
})();

var SecondModule = (function (myMethod) {
    return {
        test: function () {
            myMethod.method(); 
        }
    }
})(MyModule);
```

In both cases we have the same object, it isn't a copy. I would be grateful for any good information, advantages, disadvantages of any approach.

Comment: In the first one you are using a closure. In the second one you receive the module as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach uses the `MyModule` variable, which can be overwritten by other code, outside the module, after the `FirstModule` value has been asigned.

The second uses the `myMethod` variable, which can't (although *properties* of the object assigned to `myMethod` still can because that object is still globally available via the `MyModule` variable).

Comment: So... they're the same thing? 

Comment: @Sheraff — No, they are not.

Comment: In both cases, `MyModule.method = () => console.log('hello')` will make `.test` log `"hello"`

Comment: @Sheraff — I said that in the answer. I also said that `MyModule = {}` will have different results.

Comment: Oh I didn't think this through, did I! Maybe to make your answer clearer (because it wasn't obvious to me the first time I read it), you could says that one holds *a reference to the object* while the other *directly calls the object through the variable name*, meaning that if we reassign the variable to something else, one still has the reference to the original and the other does not.

Comment: @Sheraff — Both use variable names. Both variables hold references to an object. So that would be wrong. The only difference is the scope of the variables … one of which I called out as being a global in the answer.

Comment: @Quentin If I understand correctly, the second approach is better for security reasons. I've created a small [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qawuremeta/edit?js,console). Is that good example or should I consider something more?